# Strange issue: view controller not in focus until 2nd tap into its view on iOS7

Tags: ipad, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a strange phenomenon with my iPad part of my view controllers:
Resources are designed in a storyboard, no auto layout. The initial view controller is a UITabBarController. The first two tabs are UISplitViewControllers. The first one has a UITableView inside a UINavigationController as master view, the second has this combination as detail view. My app is ported from iOS 6.1 SDK to iOS 7 SDK, keeping backwards compatibility to iOS 6.1 down to iOS 5.1.1, thus having two storyboards.

Just when I start my app, the first button on the tab bar is not highlighted - all four buttons on the tab bar are grey. When I try to scroll the table view inside the split view, it doesn't scroll until I tapped once on the table view or on the tab bar.

It works fine on iOS 6.1 with its different storyboard, but not on iOS 7. If I don't do this intial tap and rotate the device, the tab bar button becomes blue and I can scroll the table view. Any ideas?

Here is the launch image for iPad in landscape; the detail view needs one tap to be active:

[image: launch image for iPad, landscape; detail view needs one tap to be active]